# Regex: How to consider double quotes

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex in PHP:

```
'/\|*([\w\s]*' . $searchTerm . '[\w\s]*)\|*/iu'
```

Let's assume the following searchTerm:

> stories

How do I achieve that the regex will match to a string which has double quotes, such as:

> Stories about "Neverland"

My current regex only matches just until the double quotes start. How can I cover the whole string with my regex, taking the double quotes into account?

Comment: Try adding it to the regex: `'/\|*([\w\s"]*' . $searchTerm . '[\w\s"]*)\|*/iu'`

Comment: Also don't forget to use `preg_quote()` if the input is arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor. My final regex is: '/\|*([\w\s"']*' . $searchTerm . '[\w\s"']*)\|*/iu' with both a double and a single quote after 's'. How can I escape the single quote so that my php works?

Comment: As @HamZa said you need to use `preg_quote($searchTerm)` instead of `$searchTerm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
'/\|*([\w\s\'"]*' . preg_quote($searchTerm, "/") . '[\w\s\'"]*)\|*/iu'
```

Just add the double quote and an escaped single quote (since you are using a single quoted literal to declare a regex) to the character classes `[...]`, and do not forget to escape the `$searchTerm` contents with [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) as they may contain characters like `?` or `+` that have special meaning in a regex pattern. The second argument in [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) will also escape `/` symbol as it is used as a regex delimiter in your code.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.